# Is there equivalent to python tile in Spark?

Tags: python, arrays, apache-spark, duplicates, tile

I have a numpy array in python which I wanted to duplicate itself, therefore I used
`tile(array(x), (2, 1))`

This, given an array `[1,2,3]` will return `[[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]`

But in pySpark I Have a pipelineRDD instead.
Is there a respective function for this purpose?
I am not able to find it.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no equivalent:

- RDD is a distributed collection of local object.
- RDD cannot contain another RDD.
- Local objects are limited to the size of memory and not useful to store content of a complete RDD.

You can repeat RDD in one dimension using:

```
sc.union([rdd for _ in range(n))
```

which is equivalent to

```
np.tile(a, n)
```

where n is a scalar.